# Dependency not resolved

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I cannot compile the scala code , a dependency error is popping up!

but i have another sample application which works fine with existing setup,this code is not working at the same arch

:error logs

```
 :sbt compile
[info] Set current project to firstScalaScript (in build file:/home/abu/Current%20Workspace/)
[info] Updating {file:/home/abu/Current%20Workspace/}current-workspace...
[info] Resolving org.apache.spark#spark-core;2.0.1 ...
[warn]  module not found: org.apache.spark#spark-core;2.0.1
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/abu/.ivy2/local/org.apache.spark/spark-core/2.0.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-core/2.0.1/spark-core-2.0.1.pom
[warn] ==== Akka Repository: tried
[warn]   http://repo.akka.io/releases/org/apache/spark/spark-core/2.0.1/spark-core-2.0.1.pom
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.apache.spark#spark-core;2.0.1: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
```

my code:

```
import scala.io.Source._ 
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext 
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._ 
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf 
import org.apache.log4j.Logger 
import org.apache.log4j.Level 
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD 
import org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec 

object firstScalaScript{ 
    def main(args: Array[String])
    { 
        val sc=new SparkContext(new SparkConf()) 
        val rdd=sc.textFile("e.txt,r.txt").collect()  
        //rdd.saveAsTextFile("confirmshot.txt"); sc.stop() 
    } 
}
```

Comment: my code :import scala.io.Source._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import org.apache.log4j.Level
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec


object firstScalaScript{


def main(args: Array[String]){
 val sc=new SparkContext(new SparkConf())
 val rdd=sc.textFile("e.txt,r.txt").collect()

 //rdd.saveAsTextFile("confirmshot.txt");
 sc.stop()


 }

}

Comment: Please edit your question with your code block (and set up proper formatting) instead of using comments for the same purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark artifacts (and those of many more libraries) are packaged and distributed for different versions of Scala. To distinguish between them, the Scala version is appended at the end of the artifact name, e.g. `spark-core_2.10` or `spark-core_2.11`.

Your `spark-core` dependency is incomplete, as it's missing the Scala version.

SBT can help you appending the Scala version you're using to the artifact name at build time. You can add dependency as

```
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.0.1"
```

and that will translate to

```
"org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_YOUR_SCALA_VERSION" % "2.0.1"
```

All the details about this Jar can be found in [Maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.11/2.0.1). Note that in this page you can find suggestions on how to import the lib using other tools like Maven or Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Spark dependecies has additional number in artifactId - Scala version

It should be `spark-core_2.11` for example, for Scala 2.11

In SBT it should be:

```
// Scala version will be added by SBT while building
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.0.2"
```

or:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.0.2"
```

Note: second version should not be used with libraries which has Scala dependecy, because first one will automatically choose proper artifact. Use it only with non-Scala dependencies

Comment: I wouldn't even mention the second one, it's a bad habit.

Comment: @Reactormonk Yes, it is bad habit, but it shows how it works. Later I will edit answer to focus on that :)

Comment: @Reactormonk Changed :) Thanks for your suggestions about this :)